# Custom item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to sort my item of `RecyclerView` by alphabet like this:

[image]

So could anybody let me know how to make the row has **SECTION** 
smaller than the other. Will we custom it in class `Decoration`?

Comment: the row item is under your control, padding,margin and text size

Comment: But I want only row section smaller then the other.. so where I can custom it?

Comment: how the row sections are created? i'm guessing its you then you can customise it. however if you only want only one section that be smaller than the rest, then you can achieve that by knowing the posting of the section and then do your scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use this library,

```
https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview
```

I hope you get what you want from  this link.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getItemViewType` to determine what type of view a position should hold.

```
public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
    if (dataset.get(position).isHeader()) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}
```

Then create the correct ViewHolder in `onCreateViewHolder`.

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        return HeaderViewHolder.create(parent);
    }
    else {
        return ItemViewHolder.create(parent);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you bind the correct data in `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER) {
        ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).bind(/* your heading data for this position */);
    } else {
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).bind(/* your item data for this position */);
    }
}
```

If it's not clear - create your ViewHolders to inflate separate layouts.  Your header view holder will inflate the thinner layout with different background etc.